# laravel undefined array key

Tags: arrays, foreach, frontend

Controller:-
public function index(){

```
     $data=array(DB::select('select * from product'));
    return view ('product',['products'=>$data]);
}
```

Views:-

@foreach ($products as $item)

#### {{$item['name']}}

{{$item['description']}}

@endforeach

Comment: what's the problem? what is your question?

Comment: actually i am trying to do intergation in front end but i am trying to do i am geting error a undefined array ID